# how to use gulp to call au build in a typescript aurelia cli project?

Tags: typescript, gulp, aurelia

I built an aspnetcore web project use vs207, and then use aurelia-cli (aspnetcore and typescript) created the front end. it works fine when I run au build in command prompt. but I want to use vs2017 to build it automatically when file is changed.

my gulpfile.js looks like:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var shell = require('gulp-shell');

gulp.task('build', shell.task('au build'));
```

the Task Runner Explorer can show the task correctly, but when I double click the build task, there are errors:

```
[12:31:10] Starting 'build'...
[12:31:10] 'build' errored after 14 ms
[12:31:10] Error: spawn au build ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(internal/child_process.js:178:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:474:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:388:17)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:431:11)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:999:3
Process terminated with code 1.
```

not sure the reason, is there something I miss?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to specify which Node version you want VS to use, in VS2017 you can change it in Tools \ Options \ Projects and Solutions \ Web Package Management.

Also you might also want to change the Gulp file so that you can start "au build --watch" instead of "au build". The cli already supports "au run --watch", but not "au build --watch". If you want to build on changes I think using this will be much faster than running a complete "au build"

Check out the comment here for details on how to add "au build --watch" to your gulp file:

https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues/240#issuecomment-238179488